# Ajax to php call isn't successful

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to test an ajax call on post by doing the following just for testing purposes, but for some reason the call is never successful. I've been searching around and there isn't much that I could find that would explain why this isn't working.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "file.php",
    success: function(data) {
        if(data == 'true'){
            alert("success!");
        }
    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert("Error!");
    }});
```

file.php contains the following:

```
<?php 
    return true;
?>
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction. I realize that this may seem simple but I am stumped. Thank.

Comment: install the like of firebug (for ff) for debugging

Comment: Does the return true do something? instead have some text there simply print or echo true.

Comment: I forgot to mention that this ajax call is inside of an iframe if that makes any difference. I tried it outside of an iframe and it seemed to work. Any ideas on why that would be?

Comment: How can it work if you're not making any output? return true just abort the script and returns to the OS with a boolean value..

Comment: Guys!! Whenever u trying to match string always use trim function, if u will check response length of echo 'true'; then it will return 6 instead of 4. So right way is use $.trim(data)=='true', u can't believe then check out yourself then u will agreed. if u will use echo true then it will return 1 instead of 'true', always check first what data u getting from ajax response and check length also. Okay happy Coding :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`return true` will make the script exit. You need:

```
echo 'true';
```

Comment: For some reason this still isn't working. I added a comment to my original post regarding Iframes, if that makes a difference.

Comment: it's not working because you are not trimming your response data. use $.trim(data)=='true' then it will work. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check your paths. Is `file.php` residing in the same folder as the file that your javascript is contained in?

If your path is incorrect, you will get a 404 error printed to your javascript console if you are using chrome.

Also you should change your php to:

```
<?php

echo 'true';
```

Once your path is correct and your php is amended you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried by accessing to the file directly and see if it outputs something?

return true shouldn't be use in that case (or any other, it's better to use exit or die), everything get by a AJAX call is hypertext generated by server side, you should use (as they pointed you before echo 'true';)

You could also try a traditional AJAX call XMLHttpRequest (without JQuery) if problem persists, and then check if there is any problem between the request and server..

EDIT: also, do not check by comparison, just make an alert to 'data' to see what it gets.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the echo 'true' suggestion, you can also try to alert the actual data that's returned to ajax. That way you can see if you have the proper value/type for your if statement.

```
success: function(data) {
    alert(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, the new ajax syntax

```
$.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "file.php" }).done(function(resp){
    alert(resp);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is correct way:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "file.php",
    success : function (data) {
    /* first thing, check your response length. If you are matching string
       if you are using echo 'true'; then it will return 6 length,
       Because '' or "" also considering as response. Always use trim function
       before using string match. 
    */
        alert(data.length);
        // trim white space from response
        if ($.trim(data) == 'true') {
            // now it's working :)
            alert("success!");
        }
    },
    error : function (data) {
        alert("Error!");
    }
});
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php 
echo 'true'; 
// Not return true, Because ajax return visible things.
// if you will try to echo true; then it will convert client side as '1'
// then you have to match data == 1
?>
```